# error in query for multiple result set using a dataset

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I was going through a lot of resources on how to populate a data set.And i kind of got an error when trying to populate the created data set with 4 select statements.
but my sql uses the where clause,the other statements i saw select certain columns and go to the other select statement using a semi column.

Now when i include the semi-colon between the two sql statements and try to run an error occurs telling me that `"Characters found after end of SQL statement"`.

And when i omit the semi colon another error comes with
 `"Syntax error in query expression"`.

***Is there a way to fix the problem?***

Thank you for your help.

```
    str1 = "SELECT [description] FROM [project] WHERE [project number]=@project"
    str2 = "SELECT [material number],[material type],[unit],[work_item_material_cost].[quantity],[rate],[cost/unit] FROM [work_item_material_cost]" & _
  "WHERE [work_item_material_cost].[project number]=@wimproject"
    str3 = "SELECT [labour number],[labour title],[work_item_labor_cost].[quantity],[work_item_labor_cost].[utilization factor],[indexed hourly cost],[total hourly cost] FROM [work_item_labor_cost]" & _
   "WHERE [work_item_labor_cost].[project number]=@wilproject"
    str4 = "SELECT [equipment number],[equipment type],[work_item_equipment_cost].[quantity],[work_item_equipment_cost].[utilization factor],[hourly rental rate],[total rental rate] FROM [work_item_equipment_cost]" & _
 "WHERE [work_item_equipment_cost].[project number]=@wieproject"

    currentProject = New DataSet()
    project = New DataTable("project")
    wimaterial = New DataTable("work_item_material")
    wilabour = New DataTable("work_item_labour")
    wiequipment = New DataTable("work_item_equipment")

    cmd.CommandText = str1
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project", str)
    Dim data_reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    project.Load(data_reader)
    currentProject.Tables.Add(project)
```

Comment: Are you using MSAccess?

Comment: Have you tried the `GO` statement instead of the semi column? Or use a transaction?

Comment: Have you looked into MARS (Multiple Active Record Sets)? I think you need to set up your connection to allow this if I remember correctly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Steve yes i'm using MS Access

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `MSAccess` as your database.
If this is the case then `MSAccess` doesn't support multiple select statements as your query above.
You have no alternative than issuing every select command by itself. (or use a different database).

```
string q1 = "SELECT [description] FROM [project] WHERE [project number]=?"
string q2 = "SELECT [material number],[material type],[unit],[quantity],[rate],[cost/unit] " & _
            "FROM [work_item_material_cost] WHERE [work_item_material_cost].[project number]=?" 
string q3 = "SELECT [description] FROM [project] WHERE [project number]=?"
string q4 = "SELECT [material number],[material type],[unit],[quantity],[rate],[cost/unit] " & _
            "FROM [work_item_material_cost] WHERE [work_item_material_cost].[project number]=?" 
string q5 = "SELECT [labour number],[labour title],[quantity],[utilization factor]," & _
            "[indexed hourly cost],[total hourly cost] FROM [work_item_labor_cost] " & _
             "WHERE [work_item_labor_cost].[project number]=?"
string q6 = "SELECT [equipment number],[equipment type],[quantity],[utilization factor]," & _
            "[hourly rental rate],[total rental rate] FROM [work_item_equipment_cost] " & _
            "WHERE [work_item_equipment_cost].[project number]=?"

Dim ds As DataSet = new DataSet()
Dim dt1 = new DataTable("dt1")
Dim dt2 = new DataTable("dt2")
Dim dt3 = new DataTable("dt3")
Dim dt4 = new DataTable("dt4")
Dim dt5 = new DataTable("dt5")
Dim dt6 = new DataTable("dt6")

cmd = New OleDbCommand()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = q1
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", str)
Dim rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dt1.Load(reader)
ds.Tables.Add(dt1)

cmd.CommandText = q2
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dt2.Load(reader)
ds.Tables.Add(dt2)

.... and so on for the other queries ....
```

Comment: can u explain a little bit more

Comment: I wrote the code you gave me ,but it's telling me that "No value given for one or more required parameters."Is it may be i am giving it the same criteria or what

Comment: Probably a mispelled column name or table name

Comment: BTW is variable rd OledbDatareader?but it's still giving me an error

Comment: Yes it is a OleDbDataReader implicitily defined by the context. However I need to remove the second Dim.....

Comment: Shouldn't it be like,if it is like dim rd=cmd.ExecutenonQuery().Here's the code i used anyway

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: i've found the problem but it's not showing me the right result.

Comment: @Steve I was using it for crystal reports,that's why i told you it's not showing me the right result.Do you know crystal reports?

Comment: I have used Crystal Report many years ago, (not an happy experience) but I think you need to create the DataRelation in your dataset to show correctly these data [See DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataRelation(v=vs.110).aspx)